# How could I determine the stability of these equilibrium points if $\lambda > 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

We consider the uniparametric differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \left(\lambda - x^2 + 2x\right)\left(\lambda - x^2\right).$$
I want to determine the equilibrium points as well as their stability depending on $\lambda$.

I know that (correct me if I'm wrong) if $\lambda < -1$ then there don't exist equilibrium points; if $-1 < \lambda < 0$ then the equilibrium points are $x_1 = 1 + \sqrt{1 + \lambda}$ (unstable) and $x_2 = 1 - \sqrt{1 + \lambda}$ (stable); if $\lambda > 0$ then the equilibrium points are $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3 = \sqrt{\lambda}$ and $x_4 = -\sqrt{\lambda}$; if $\lambda = -1$ then it is $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ (unstable), and if $\lambda = 0$ then they are $x_1 = 2$ (unstable) and $x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 0$ (stable).

How could I determine the stability of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ if $\lambda > 0$? Which cases should I consider and how can I realize? Moreover, I know that an equilibrium point is stable if it is asymptotically stable considering a one-dimensional system, but how could I notice that an equilibrium point is asymptotically stable, as well as stable?

Comment: Can you draw the Direction Plot and investigate slope results to determine stability?

Comment: @Moo What do you mean by "Direction Plot"?

Comment: Slope field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field#:~:text=A%20slope%20field%20(also%20called,functions%20drawn%20as%20solid%20curves. See: https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/math/calculus/direction-fields/

Comment: How did you determine the stability for the case in your post? You simply stated some points were stable and some were not. Could whatever procedure you used for those points work for $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: @Moo Oh I see!! Thanks!! But I would like to determine stability without resorting to direction fields. I did it for the other cases by showing that the flow ($f(x) = \left(\lambda - x^2 + 2x\right)\left(\lambda - x^2\right)$) is increasing or decreasing in a neighbourhood of each equilibrium point.

Comment: @whpowell96 I tried. For example, if $-1 < \lambda < 0$ then $x_1 = 1 + \sqrt{1 + \lambda} \in (1, 2)$, so I am able to say that $f$ is increasing in a neighbourhood of $x_1$, hence $x_1$ is unstable. However, if $\lambda > 0$ then I don't know which cases I could consider in order to show the stability or instability of the four equilibrium points.